# NOT EXISTS with NULLs not consistent with other operators

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the initial data:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
    (
    Id integer,
    Surname varchar(50),
    DOB datetime
    )   
INSERT INTO #data
values 
(1,'smith', null),
(2,'jones', '01 jan 1970'),
(3,'vernon', null),
(4,'smith', '01 jan 1970'),
(5,'jones', '01 jan 1970'),
(6,'vernon', '01 jan 1970'),
(7,null, '01 jan 1970')
```

Here is a list of exclusions:

```
CREATE TABLE #exclusions
    (
    ExcludedSurname varchar(50),
    ExcludedDOB datetime
    )   
INSERT INTO #exclusions
values 
('smith', '01 jan 1970'),
('jones', '01 jan 1970'),
('vernon', null),
(null, '01 jan 1970')
```

Here is a query that returns my slightly unexpected result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #data a
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #exclusions e
    WHERE
            a.DOB = e.ExcludedDOB and
            a.Surname = e.ExcludedSurname
    )
```

To ensure `Id`s 3 and 7 are excluded I can do this ugly change to the script. There's lots of possible data in the production tables (live version of #data is 1000m records) - that is why I've picked such far out replacements to `null`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM #data a
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #exclusions e
    WHERE  
            ISNULL(a.DOB, '01 JAN 2200') = ISNULL(e.ExcludedDOB, '01 JAN 2200')  and
            ISNULL(a.Surname,'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA') = ISNULL(e.ExcludedSurname,'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
    )
```

Here it is on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/891b6/1)

Is there a more elegant way of doing the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PostgreSQL ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/654a1/4)) you could use

```
WHERE (a.DOB, a.Surname) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (e.ExcludedDOB, e.ExcludedSurname)
```

But SQL Server is missing two items for this to work. [row value constructors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231) and [IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate)

Meanwhile you can use the technique from here: [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM   #data a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   #exclusions e
                   WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT a.DOB,
                                         a.Surname
                                  INTERSECT
                                  SELECT e.ExcludedDOB,
                                         e.ExcludedSurname))
```

A variation of the above uses `EXCEPT`(live example **[HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/654a1/1)**):

```
SELECT *
FROM   #data a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT a.DOB, 
                      a.Surname
               EXCEPT
               SELECT e.ExcludedDOB, 
                      e.ExcludedSurname 
               FROM #exclusions e)
```

Comment: awesome. it will be interesting to know why nulls are treated differently when comparing.

Comment: @shahkalpesh - What you mean why they are treated as equal when doing a `DISTINCT/UNION/EXCEPT/INTERSECT/GROUP BY` but not when doing `=`? Yes it is inconsistent.

Comment: @MartinSmith rather than using `INTERSECT` this query will be more readable using `Except`

Comment: @MartinSmith; just added it to the answer - please delete if you feel it is less readable.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok - I should have tested: can I add this to the answer? [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/654a1/1)

Comment: @whytheq - Ah see what you mean. Yes think the `NOT EXISTS ... EXISTS` was there because I took your original query and adjusted the join condition. Agree that is simpler. Your original comment just mentioned replacing `INTERSECT` with `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @MartinSmith no worries: can I add this option to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

@MartinSmith

Check out this alternative:

```
SELECT *
FROM   #data a
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT a.Surname,
                     a.DOB
              EXCEPT
              SELECT e.ExcludedSurname,
                     e.ExcludedDOB
              FROM   #exclusions e)
```

Very elegant and readable.

---

Although why bother with the EXISTS in the above seems like EXCEPT does all the work?

```
SELECT Surname,
       DOB
FROM   #data
EXCEPT
SELECT ExcludedSurname,
       ExcludedDOB
FROM   #exclusions
```

[supplied my a friend of mine - who unfortunately doesn't contribute `SO` - well not that I know of]

Both alternatives are here on [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/654a1/12)

Comment: There is a `from` missing in the first select.

Comment: The second one doesn't do the same thing in that you can't return the `Id` column from `data`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Server doesn't require a `FROM` clause.  It is referencing the columns from the outer row.

Answer (score 1):

If your exclusions have no duplicates, wouldn't phrasing this as a `left outer join` at least look cleaner:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #data a left outer join
     #exclusions e
     on a.DOB = e.ExcludedDOB and
        a.Surname = e.ExcludedSurname
where e.ExcludedDOB is NULL and e.ExcludedSurname is null
```

You can then handle the NULLs with either a `coalesce` or with logic (this example shows both):

```
SELECT * 
FROM #data a left outer join
     #exclusions e
     on (a.DOB = e.ExcludedDOB or a.DOB is NULL and e.ExcludedDOB is NULL) and
        (coealesce(a.Surname, '<null>') = coalesce(e.ExcludedSurname, '<null>')
where e.ExcludedDOB is NULL and e.ExcludedSurname is null
```

The downside to all these approaches is that I don't think they will take advantage of indexes on the exclusions table . . . which could be a good idea if the table is large.  One approach requires two joins, but fixes this problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #data a left outer join
     #exclusions e
     on a.DOB = e.ExcludedDOB and
        a.Surname = e.ExcludedSurname left outer join
     #exclusions enull
     on enull.ExcludedSurname is null and a.Surname is NULL and
        enull.ExcludedDOB = a.DOB
where e.ExcludedDOB is NULL and e.ExcludedSurname is null and
      enull.ExcludedDOB is NULL and enull.ExcludedSurname is null
```

However, Martin's approach might still be the best performing.

If you don't need the `id` from #data, then the simplest way is:

```
select Surname, Dob
from #data
except (select ExcludedSurname, ExcludedDB from #exceptions)
```

I use this construct often for table comparison.  However, to get the id, you are left with the problem of NULLs in the joins.

Comment: +1 although your middle script is excluding `Id`=1 which should be included in the result set. Maybe you could amend the first condition of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `(a.DOB = e.ExcludedDOB or a.DOB is NULL and e.ExcludedDOB is null)`

Comment: @whytheq . . . I fixed that problem.  The last version still will not include that.  I think getting the DOB being NULL, and using indexes, would require a third join to #exlusions.